# Manga about a man who can't feel heat

Tags: story-identification, manga

There is a man who is born with a disability that means he can't feel heat, so his body temperature always gets really low. He meets the other MC and discovers that he can feel this person's body heat.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Roughly when did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [*Hold Me Tight*](https://manhuascan.com/manga-hold-me-tight-revised.html)?

> Every day of Giovanni’s life has been cold. Despite scorching summers,
> sunny springs, despite being the president of an uber rich company, he
> is incapable of feeling warmth, numb to it all. Then, he met Felix.
> Shy and seemingly innocent, Felix’s touch is the first heat Giovanni’s
> felt in a lifetime. Lust or love, Giovanni hires him as his personal
> bodyguard, but are Felix’s true motives so warmhearted?

[image]

Comment: For the record, this isn't really a fantasy comic so much as a thinly veiled excuse for gay pornography but it does have some fantasy *elements*, which means that it's on topic.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's [*The Relationship Between Heat and Love*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/joosbsf/the-relationship-between-heat-and-love) (AKA *Heat and Love)*.

> Ji Gwi, a lad who became a heated ghost after loving Queen Sun Duk one-sidedly. Eun Chong, a descendant of Ji Gwi, found that by touching the Hong Kong exchange student Hae Bum, his body temperature lowers. So seeking help -"If the type of touching changes the body temperature, shouldn't we progress this further?" Due to the very forward Hae Bum, Eun Chong's life becomes shaken.
>
> [image]